# Testflight app compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, beta

I had a beta test running on a universal app that was working on both iPhones and iPads.  I'm not sure what changed, because I didn't make any changes to the project that would cause the compatibility to change, but at some point my app started showing up in TestFlight as iPhone only.  I've checked all my code signing and provisioning certificates and I really don't see what could be the problem.  I've even created new ones and used them with the same result.  In the developer member center there doesn't appear to be any where to actually specify iPhone or iPad unless I'm just missing something.

If I build and upload my app as Universal, it comes through as iPhone only.  If I build and upload as "iPad", it comes through as "Requires iOS 8.2 or later" but shows incompatible on both iPads and iPhones.

Comment: iTunes connect shows the following for "Device family" :iPhone / iPod Touch, iPad

But on TestFlight on an iOS device it shows iPhone only.

Comment: Joshua Jackson, I am facing same issue with my app, can you please share the solution if possible ?

Comment: @Gaurav - apparently my answer had been deleted because I didn't have enough detail in addition to the link to Apple's page.

Please look at my answer below and vote for it.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the functionality requirements set in the info.plist can restrict device compatibility, specifically "gps", "sms", and "telephony" restrict the device to iPhone only regardless of compatibility settings.

See link below

[Apple compatibility matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

Comment: @200OK I have edited the answer to add more specifics in addition to the link.  Please vote for it.

Comment: Thanks Joshua Jackson for getting back to me, I don't think so that i have used specific settings to restrict to iPhone, Here are my permissions : camera-flash,armv7,front-facing-camera,still-camera. Please share your thoughts and let me know if something going wrong.

Comment: @Gaurav look at the compatibility matrix in the link please!  Camera-flash is listed as incompatible with iPads.

Comment: You are right buddy, There is no camera flash permission for iPads. it was camera-flash permission issue. Now its working fine on iPads too.
Thanks dude...